# Java servlet for testing of different versions of sales copy

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I want to build a Java web app for the following purpose:

1. I run a Google AdWords campaign.
2. When the user clicks on the ad, he or she goes to URL A.
3. I also have a very simple web shop. It has a separate page for each of the items sold there. Let's say I have URLs B, C and D for items 1, 2 and 3, respectively.
4. When an item is sold, some text is displayed on the page. By searching for this text the web app gets to know, whether the respective item is available or not.
5. Let's say that at the start of the Google AdWords campaign these 3 items are available.
6. When items 1, 2 and 3 are available, the web app should redirect from URL A to URLs B, C and D in equal proportions (if 9 people visit URL A, 3 of them should go to B, 3 - to C and 3 - to D).
7. Let's assume that item 2 is sold. Now the list of URLs of available products is equal to B, D.
8. In this case, the web app should also redirect visitors from A to B and D in equal proportions.
9. When item 1 is sold, the web app should redirect visitors from A to D all the time.
10. When all items are sold, the web app should direct visitors to some default page (hard-coded).

Main purpose of the web app is to ensure that people from Google AdWords always land on a page with one available product.

Note that items can be sold not only because of the Google AdWords campaign, but also by visitors, which come to the web site by themselves.

Therefore, the web app should check in regular intervals  (e. g. 5 minutes) which of the URLs link to available (not sold) items.

How can I build a **simple** web app, which

1. redirects visitors of URL A to different URLs (the list of URLs being stored in memory) and
2. in regular intervals checks the availability of the items?

What is the **simplest** way to do it?

I know that I can setup a Quartz job, which can update the list of URLs in a text file, but I want something that runs inside the web app container, something minimal.

Comment: Simplest way is to *not* store the URLs "in memory" and to *not* check for availability "in regular intervals" but to *use a database*.

Comment: Wouldn't a database be an overkill for 50 URLs?

Comment: How do you know if your items have been sold or not?  There's a lot of missing information here. Plus I really think this question is off-topic. But in any case, a database is pretty much required to do *anything* in a webapp, unless you want to invent your own database engine using text files. Because you always need to store and retrieve things from some kind of database. Unless you're hosting this on a 386, why are you so concerned about it?